# Как перезаписать значение атрибута на JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Мне нужно перезаписывать значения атрибута src для дальнейшей работы с тегом img, значение записывается как временное и когда мне надо извлечь потом новое значение src я в итоге ничего не получаю.

```
    var author_track = obj.querySelector('.track-name');
    var img = obj.querySelector('img');
    if (author_track) {
        var name = author_track.innerHTML.match(/(.+)\s+-\s+.+/);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/serializers/AlbumAudioTrack/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                author_track: name[1]
            },
            success: function (album) {
                if (album[0]) {
                    img.src = album[0].photo;
                } else {
                    img.removeAttribute('src');
                    img.setAttribute('src', '/media/user_16131596871613159687/photo/AlbumDefault.jpg');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(img.src);
```

Есть решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Вы уверены, что оно вообще записывается?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

Comment: да записывает, если проверку сделать внутри ajax запроса

Comment: Не нужны тебе атрибуты вообще.

Comment: И console.log выкинь.

Answer (score 1):

А так не вариант?

```
var author_track = obj.querySelector('.track-name');
    var img = obj.querySelector('img');
    if (author_track) {
        var name = author_track.innerHTML.match(/(.+)\s+-\s+.+/);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/serializers/AlbumAudioTrack/',
            async: false, 
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                author_track: name[1]
            },
            success: function (album) {
                if (album[0]) {
                    img.src = album[0].photo;
                } else {
                    img.src = '/media/user_16131596871613159687/photo/AlbumDefault.jpg';
                }
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(img.src);
```

Изменил сделал запрос синхронным, раз вы не можете обрабатывать асинхронные запросы

А через асинхронный так нужно проверять

```
var author_track = obj.querySelector('.track-name');
var img = obj.querySelector('img');
if (author_track) {
    var name = author_track.innerHTML.match(/(.+)\s+-\s+.+/);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/serializers/AlbumAudioTrack/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            author_track: name[1]
        },
        success: function (album) {
            if (album[0]) {
                img.src = album[0].photo;
            } else {
                img.src = '/media/user_16131596871613159687/photo/AlbumDefault.jpg';
            }
            console.log(img.src);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: К сожалению нет, возвращается значение которое было по дефолту, то есть ничего =(

Comment: Правильно это ajax. Вам нужно смотреть по ответу

Comment: console.log выкинь.

Comment: Да, через синхронный выводит то что надо, спасибо.

Comment: Да, я знаю, что проверка внутри запроса дает то, что запрашиваю, просто далее я хочу использовать новое значение src после условия, а при дальнейшем использовании переменной img оно возвращает дефолтное значение, а не то, что я получил по гету.

Comment: @Jony в любом случае если ответ помог то можете пометить как полезный

Answer (score 0):

Вся причина в том, что `console.log(img.src)` выполняется до того, как выполнится запрос `ajax()`, так как это асинхронный запрос. Вы можете использовать метод `then()`, чтобы решить проблему.

```
var author_track = obj.querySelector('.track-name');
var img = obj.querySelector('img');
if (author_track) {
    var name = author_track.innerHTML.match(/(.+)\s+-\s+.+/);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/serializers/AlbumAudioTrack/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            author_track: name[1]
        },
        success: function (album) {
            if (album[0]) {
                img.src = album[0].photo;
            } else {
                img.removeAttribute('src');
                img.setAttribute('src', '/media/user_16131596871613159687/photo/AlbumDefault.jpg');
            }
        }
    }).then(function(){
        console.log(img.src);
    });
}
```